# How long google Page Speed Insight take to update Field Data

Tags: lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I m boosting my website performance . I'm testing my website page speed with Google PSI. I've done maximum correction and i'm getting 90+ score in PSI . All lab data attributes are green . But Field data is still not being updated. I m just wondering, how long Google page speed insight take to update the Field data. also, If Fields data will update, then it will be same as the Lab data ?

[Page Insight Screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM3O2.png)

Answer (score 2):

The data displayed is aggregated daily, so the data should change day to day.

However the reason you do not see the results of any improvements you make instantly is because the data is taken over a rolling 28 day period.

After about 7 days you should start to see your score improve, in 28 days the report data will be reflective of changes you made today.

Because of this delay I would recommend taking your own metrics using the [Web Vitals Library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) so you can see the results in real time. This also lets you verify the changes you made work at all screen sizes and cross browser.

Either that or you could query the [CrUX data set](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report) yourself on shorter timescales.